# UIDatePicker in time mode - How to get the only "hour value"

Tags: iphone, ios, datepicker

I am wondering how to get the only hour value from `UIDatePicker`.

Basically, it gets the time value like `13:34` collecting from (e.g `[dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date]`).

However what I wanna get the one is; only hour value → 13 instead of 13:34

Would be great help if anybody show part of a source code.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormat setDateFormat:@"HH"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the date format of dateFormatter to get what you want.  For example:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
NSString *hourString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: datePicker.date];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> NSDateFormatter *datePickerFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
> [datePickerFormat setDateFormat:@"HH"]; 
> NSString *datePickerStringToSave = [datePickerFormat stringFromDate:datePicker.date]; 
 NSLog(@"%@",datePickerStringToSave);
```

for mor information on date format patterns please check these out http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score -1):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
NSString *hour=[formatter stringFromDate:[timePicker date]];
```